# Pgfplots grid not showing

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having trouble with setting up a grid for this plot using `pgfplots`.

[image]

Here's my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    /pgf/declare function = {
        signal = 0.8 * (sin(deg(x)) + 0.7*sin(2*deg(x)) + 0.7*sin(3*deg(x)));
    }
]

\begin{axis}[
    grid = minor,
    height= 0.35\textwidth,
    width = 0.8\textwidth,
    thick,
    scale=1.8,
    axis lines=center,
    domain=0:20*pi,
    samples=500,
    line join=bevel,
    xlabel=t,
    ymax=2.7,
    ymin=-2.7,
    xmax=25.9,
    xmin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
] 
\addplot[ultra thick,black!40!cyan] { signal };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is this problem related to the setting of the axis lines?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Thanks for providing most of the required code.  But, for future reference, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: you could change your `xtick=\empty` to, for example,  `minor xtick={0,2,...,60},`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to see the grid do not say `xtick=\empty` and/or `ytick=\empty`. Use `xticklabels=\empty` and `yticklabels=\empty` to not show the `ticklabels`, `major thick length=0` and `minor thick length=0` to not show the ticks.

You only want to see the minor grid? Or both? For the minor grid you have to set a `minor tick num`. In the following example I use both grids with `minor thick num=3` and I color the `major grid` red.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    /pgf/declare function = {
        signal = 0.8 * (sin(deg(x)) + 0.7*sin(2*deg(x)) + 0.7*sin(3*deg(x)));
    }
]

\begin{axis}[
    grid = both,
    minor tick num=3,
    every major grid/.style={red, opacity=0.5},
    height= 0.35\textwidth,
    width = 0.8\textwidth,
    thick,
    scale=1.8,
    axis lines=center,
    domain=0:20*pi,
    samples=500,
    line join=bevel,
    xlabel=t,
    ymax=2.7,
    ymin=-2.7,
    xmax=25.9,
    xmin=0,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    yticklabels=\empty,
    major tick length=0pt,
    minor tick length=0pt,
    %xtick=\empty,
    %ytick=\empty,
] 
\addplot[ultra thick,black!40!cyan] { signal };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```